# Where to find System.DirectoryServices in ASP.NET Core 2.0?

Tags: asp.net-core, active-directory, nuget, asp.net-core-2.0

I need to run some Active Directory queries with a new  ASP.NET Core 2.0 web application.  Microsoft's documentation says the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement [libraries are available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=netcore-2.0&term=System.DirectoryServices) as part of .NET Core 2.0.

How do I find the associated packages in NuGet which include this namespace?  The only one I see in NuGet is an unsupported library by someone other than Microsoft.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, [System.DirectoryServices are scheduled for .net core 2.1 not .net core 2.0](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/pull/444).

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2089 is the original issue log

Comment: Does that mean the listing at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=netcore-2.0&term=System.DirectoryServices is not correct and needs to be fixed?

Comment: It could well be; it seems like a last minute decision.

Comment: I have the error on netcore 3.1 :S

Answer (score 9):

I have a better solution for this thread. I found a Nuget package (it's in Pre-Release) called "Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility" that provides the System.DirectoryServices namespace you are looking for. Just search Nuget, make sure you have the Pre-Release option checked, and you will find it. Most everything will work once you get it. Just make sure to update the package later on, when it's finalized. Hope that helps someone, took me a couple weeks to track it down.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it now in NetCore 2.2 there is support for this package:

> System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

You can find it in nuget.

Author is Microsoft and

Date Published: Tuesday, May 29, 2018 (5/29/2018)

Answer (score 0):

With "Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility", it will compile but you'll get a platform not supported exception at runtime if you are not running on Windows.

```
    Unhandled Exception: System.PlatformNotSupportedException: System.DirectoryServices is not supported on this platform.
     at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry..ctor(String path)
     at ad_test.ActiveDirectoryClient.GetUsername(String emailAddress) in .../ad-test/ActiveDirectoryClient.cs:line 24
     at ad_test.Program.Main(String[] args) in .../ad-test/Program.cs:line 11
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a pre-release version for System.DirectoryServices. You can get it from NuGet package manager using this command:

> Install-Package System.DirectoryServices -Version
>   4.5.0-preview1-25914-04

This is working fine for me till now.